# Android RSA1024 Encryption: Data length Exception on Android 4.0.4 and below

Tags: android, exception, rsa

please allow me to present this problem in a few sentence.
Actually, my code work on Android 4.1 to 4.2 nicely. However, the same code and the same input that i used for testing on Android 4.1 caused exception on Android 4.0.4. i can't find any solution yet.

i have tried using `Cipher.doFinal(ByteBuffer input,ByteBuffer output)`, but the output seems always did nothing.

Following is my code:

```
public static Cipher RSA1024Cipher(int mode)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException, InvalidKeySpecException,
        UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Cipher RsaCipher;
    RsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(Base64.decode(RSAModulus,
            Base64.DEFAULT));//RSAModulus is provided out of this block of code.

    // Log.d("RSA Encryption:", "modulus:" + modulus);
    BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(Base64.decode(RSAExponent,
            Base64.DEFAULT));//RSAExponent is provided out of this block of code.
    // Log.d("RSA Encryption:", "Exponent:" + exponent);
    RSAPublicKeySpec KeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
    KeyFactory keyFact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey pk = keyFact.generatePublic(KeySpec);
    RsaCipher.init(mode, pk);

    return RsaCipher;

}
// the data byte array should always be size of 8, UTF-8 based.
public static String RSA1024EncryptionToBase64String(final byte[] data) {
    try {

        Cipher RsaCipher = RSA1024Cipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);

        System.out.println(RsaCipher.getBlockSize());//i got 117
        System.out.println(data.length);//this return 8
        // Log.d("Base64UnEncryptedByteData", new String(data));
        byte[] CipherText = RsaCipher.doFinal(data);
        System.out.println(CipherText.length);
        System.out.println(new String(CipherText));
        byte[] base64 = Base64.encode(CipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP);//NO_WRAP for sure
        // Log.d("Base64ByteData", new String(base64));
        return new String(base64);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

And this is the Exception message shown while running on Android 4.0.4

```
08-13 10:01:40.075: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException: input too large for RSA cipher.
08-13 10:01:40.075: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RSACoreEngine.convertInput(RSACoreEngine.java:115)
08-13 10:01:40.075: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RSABlindedEngine.processBlock(RSABlindedEngine.java:95)
08-13 10:01:40.075: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.encodings.PKCS1Encoding.encodeBlock(PKCS1Encoding.java:184)
08-13 10:01:40.075: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.encodings.PKCS1Encoding.processBlock(PKCS1Encoding.java:132)
08-13 10:01:40.075: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCERSACipher.engineDoFinal(JCERSACipher.java:467)
08-13 10:01:40.075: E/AndroidRuntime(13141):    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1106)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:**
No matter the data byte array size is. The exception will always throw.

Comment: Please can you provide sample values for `RSAModulus` and `RSAExponent`? Side note: Java variable names should be `camelCase` not `TitleCase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `new BigInteger(1, Base64.decode(RSAModulus, Base64.DEFAULT))`, same for the exponent, or you will be dealing with negative numbers. RSA values are always positive.

Comment: Good thinking - this sounds like a plausible solution.

Comment: @Duncan especially since OpenSSL's big number (`bn`) library does not use signed values, only positive values. So it is likely converted back to it's original meaning. Bouncy simply uses `BigInteger`